# Unable to navigate to a state

Tags: angularjs

I have defined a edit state /edit and when I click on Edit Instance D1 it won't goto that route

```
<a ng-href="#/instance/edit">Edit Instance D1</a>
```

JS

```
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url : '/home',
        templateUrl : 'instance-view.html',
        controller : 'instanceListController'
    })
    .state('instance', {
        url : '/instance',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('instance.detail', {
        url : '/:id',
        templateUrl : 'data-view.html',
        controller : 'specDataListController'
    })
    .state('instance.edit', {
        url: '/edit',
        templateUrl : 'edit-table.html',
        controller : 'editInstanceController'
    });
```

});

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/1jyReALiXSpB0dJmmuQu?p=info

Comment: `ui-router` is using `ui-sref` instead of angular's `ng-href`.

Comment: I changed to <a ui-sref="edit" class="ng-scope">Edit Instance D1</a> but i get error : Error: Could not resolve 'edit' from state 'instance.detail'

Comment: The router doesn't have any way to know the `edit` is not the ID of an instance for which you want to see the detail. The URLs of the last two states are in conflict. Use a regex to tell ui-router that /:id should only consider numeric IDs, for example:https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters

Comment: You have to use the state name: `ui-sref="instance.edit"`, but more importantly, @JBNizet comment. The state that uses the url `/:id` conflicts with the other states. Use a different URL there like: `/instance/:id`.

Comment: I have changed to ui-sref="instance.edit" but the template doesn't load on first click. Only after I click "Edit Instance D1" second time the edit page shows up what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) the router will interpret edit as an id and never hit the /edit.

You may, as also suggested by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) use an numeric value for your id's and add the following to your route:

`url : '/{id:[0-9]{1,8}}'`

or you could have ids that include non-numeric letters and split your route in view/:id and edit/:id:

```
.state('instance.detail', {
            url : '/view/:id',
            templateUrl : 'data-view.html',
            controller : 'specDataListController'
        })
        .state('instance.edit', {
            url: '/edit/:id',
            templateUrl : 'edit-table.html',
            controller : 'editInstanceController'
        });
```

You'll also have to update your links in your views.

See my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/F3Z0bX8ePKQABrGoEPpL?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you but the edit page doesn't show up the first time. Only after clicking "Edit Instance" second time the dom loads

Comment: Are you sure? In my Plunker it shows up after the first click. Home page [click "Open Instance D1"] -> view page [click "Open Instance D1"] -> Edit page

Comment: You were right. Was something fishy with the link. Try the new link I've just added.